# Recover accidently deleted eclipse ini File

Tags: android, data-recovery, eclipse

I accidentaly switched my Eclipse ini file with an android Eclipse ini file. I did not create a backup of the old ini file, so that option is out of the door. I don't know where to get a working one, nor do I know how to fix the current one. Does anybody have any insight as to how to fix this, and restore my old one?

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1524M
-Declipse.buildId=v22.2.1-833290
```

Thats the current one in case you were wondering. I believe it is in the product package info, but I'm not 100% sure. Unfortunately Eclipse wont start because

> The Eclipse executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library.

**Edit:**

I also just tried opening from the terminal, but I get this error, it provides a bit more insight:

> plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_1.1.200.v20120913-144807: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: What happens if you just delete the file? For most applications, the defaults are recreated if missing.

Comment: @terdon I'll try that when i get back from my soccer game, that command is just `rm (file location) ` correct?

Comment: Yes, or safer, `mv file.ini file.ini.backup` so you can put it back if necessary.

Comment: @terdon Worked! However there is one problem, the eclipse.ini file never restores itself. I need this in order to change the java heap space.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the file. A new one with the default settings will probably be created the next time your run Eclipse. To be on the safe side, just make a copy of it:

```
mv /path/to/eclipse.ini ~/eclipse.ini.backup
```

Then, run `eclipse` again and everything should be back to normal.

Comment: The problem is it runs, but no new one is created.

Comment: @DuhProgrammer13 yes, that's not a problem. That means that the file is not necessary and in its absence, eclipse will just work with the defaults. If you want to make any special changes to it, just create a new file with the appropriate name and add them there.

Comment: OK, but i don't know how to create a file that will work with eclipse... I probably will create one that also won't run

Comment: @DuhProgrammer13 the point is that the file is not needed. If you want to do something specific, just post a question asking how. Alternatively, tell me which file you actually deleted (I still don't know if it was your personal one, which is what I assume, or a system-wide one) and I could provide you with some more options. Reinstalling eclipse would probably bring one back for example.

Comment: it was the one in /usr/lib/eclipse/eclipse.ini